# Суммирование значений одинаковых объектов

Tags: jquery, массивы, объекты

```js
var dataRow = [{id:1, sum: 10}, {id:2, sum: 15}, {id:1, sum: 20}];
var obj = {};
$(dataRow).each(function(e, i){
    obj[i.id] = i.sum;
});
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

На выходе получается:

```
{
  "1": 20,
  "2": 15
}
```

а надо чтобы у объектов с одинаковым значением `id` суммировался `sum`

на выходе должен получится объект вот в таком виде:

```
{
  "1": 30, //  10 + 20
  "2": 15
}
```

Comment: начните с того, что `+= i.sum`  напишите, потом решите проблему с `NaN`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Замените простое присваивание

```
obj[i.id] = i.sum;
```

на присваивание со сложением, например вот так

```
obj[i.id] = (obj[i.id] || 0) + i.sum;
```

```js
var dataRow = [{id:1, sum: 10}, {id:2, sum: 15}, {id:1, sum: 20}];
var obj = {};
$(dataRow).each(function(e, i){
    obj[i.id] = (obj[i.id] || 0) + i.sum;
});
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Отлично, то что надо. Спасибо!